# Does the leaf type of an array implementation data type follow type reference?

Tags: autosar

In the `SWS_Rte_07111` of the [AUTOSAR_SWS_RTE](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/standards/R22-11/CP/AUTOSAR_SWS_RTE.pdf) document it says:

> For each Array Implementation Data Type which *leaf* ImplementationDataTypeElement is typed by an ImplementationDataType [...]

In this sentence, to get to the "leaf", should I follow an eventual element of category `TYPE_REFERENCE`?

If I do and if the `TYPE_REFERENCE` refers to a `BaseType`, then `SWS_Rte_02317` and `SWS_Rte_07110` applies. If I don't then `SWS_Rte_07111` and `SWS_Rte_02318` applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence says that the properties of the `ImplementationDataTypeElement` are described by an `ImplementationDataType`, which means that the attribute `category` of the `ImplementationDataTypeElement` is set to `TYPE_REFERENCE`.

But the "leaf element" is still an `ImplementationDataTypeElement`, not an `ImplementationDataType`.

But it may be that the `ImplementationDataType` to which the `ImplementationDataTypeElement` refers to sets that value of attribute `category` again to `TYPE_REFERENCE`.

So, you might need to resolve a chain of type references until you arrive at the actually applicable data type.